# compiling error about the example of The Keyword parser options.cpp

Tags: boost-spirit

I was compiling the newest keyword example `options.cpp` with the newest Spirit got by svn. But I got the following error:

> options.cpp(26) : error C2065: “int32_t”: undefined identifier
>   options.cpp(31) : error C3203: “pair”: can't be template variant ...

I don't know why.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem in the example (which I have fixed in SVN). The fixed version will be available with Boost V1.47.

In case you're interested: the reason was that `int32_t` is not a predefined type when using MSVC. I assume the author developed the example using g++, where this type is defined.